# HLSL Computation - process pixels in order?

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl, gpgpu

Imagine I want to, say, compute the first one million terms of the Fibonacci sequence using the GPU. *(I realize this will exceed the precision limit of a 32-bit data type - just used as an example)*

Given a GPU with 40 shaders/stream processors, and cheating by using a reference book, I can break up the million terms into 40 blocks of 250,000 strips, and seed each shader with the two start values:

> unit 0: 1,1 (which then calculates 2,3,5,8,blah blah blah)
>
> unit 1: 250,000th term
>
> unit 2: 500,000th term
>
> ...

How, if possible, could I go about ensuring that pixels are processed in order? If the first few pixels in the input texture have values (with RGBA for simplicity)

```
0,0,0,1 // initial condition
0,0,0,1 // initial condition
0,0,0,2
0,0,0,3
0,0,0,5
...
```

How can I ensure that I don't try to calculate the 5th term before the first four are ready?

I realize this could be done in multiple passes but setting a "ready" bit whenever a value is calculated, but that seems incredibly inefficient and sort of eliminates the benefit of performing this type of calculation on the GPU.

OpenCL/CUDA/etc probably provide nice ways to do this, but I'm trying (for my own edification) to get this to work with XNA/HLSL.

Links or examples are appreciated.

**Update/Simplification**

Is it possible to write a shader that uses values from one pixel to influence the values from a neighboring pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot determine the order the pixels are processed. If you could, that would break the massive pixel throughput of the shader pipelines. What you can do is calculating the Fibonacci sequence using the non-recursive formula.

In your question, you are actually trying to serialize the shader units to run one after another. You can use the CPU right away and it will be much faster.

By the way, multiple passes aren't as slow as you might think, but they won't help you in your case. You cannot really calculate any next value without knowing the previous ones, thus killing any parallelization.

Comment: I'm not trying to get the shaders to run in series; that would be silly. My thought was that by breaking it up into strips (one big chunk per shader), they could still run in parallel, but it seems that level of control isn't possible. So, to be clear, it's not possible to write a shader that uses values from one pixel to calculate the value for another pixel?

Comment: Also +1 for hinting at a direct approach for calculating Fibonacci terms without recursion or iteration. Nifty. I must've skipped that day in LinAl class.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form

Comment: @David Lively: Yes, in short, it is not possible to write a shader that uses values from one pixel to calculate the value for another pixel (in a single pass).